# misalignment while using @{}c@{} and multicolumn toghether

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a recurring error when I restrict the columns of a table using @{}c@{} in the table declaration and use multicolumn at the same time. I give an example.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ @{}l@{} || @{}c@{} | @{}c@{} |@{}c@{} || @{}c@{} | @{}c@{} | @{}c@{} || @{}c@{} | @{}c@{} |@{}c@{} }
$h$&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{TITLE1} & \multicolumn{ 3 }{c||}{TITLE2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TITLE3} \\ \hline 
Domain& bbb& aaa& CCCCC& bbb& aaa& ccc& bbb& aaa& ccc\\ \hline \hline 
NAME &\textbf{1}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{1}&61.2&\textbf{20.3}&33.7&12012.8&\textbf{3622.3}&\textbf{3622.3}\\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see in the correspondence of TITLE1 and TITLE2 there is a misalignment of the vertical lines.

How can I fix it? This is a minimal misalignment but I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug with default `\multicolumn`. If you load `\usepackage{array}` it will fix the issue.

[image]

---

However, there's another fix that I'd personally recommend.

If you want to remove the spaces around each column, you'd better use

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```

instead of spamming `@{}` around each column type.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ l || c | c | c || c | c | c || c | c | c }

$h$&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{TITLE1} & \multicolumn{ 3 }{c||}{TITLE2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TITLE3} \\ \hline 
Domain& bbb& aaa& CCCCC& bbb& aaa& ccc& bbb& aaa& ccc\\ \hline \hline 
NAME &\textbf{1}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{1}&61.2&\textbf{20.3}&33.7&12012.8&\textbf{3622.3}&\textbf{3622.3}\\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And now everything is aligned perfectly and the spaces are gone without any additional packages.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer!!!! Thanks so much